# Can we have a controller for the child item view specified in a Ember.CollectionView?

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to set a controller for the child item view specified in a `CollectionView`, but the controller is not getting initiated automatically and the JsFiddle is [available here](http://jsfiddle.net/VenkataSuresh/tcMqb/), so any ideas for creating child view controllers?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used the `CollectionView` but seems to me that what you are looking for is the `itemController` property of `ArrayController`

Basically if you define something like:

```
App.Product = Ember.Object.extend();
App.ProductController = Ember.ObjectContoller.extend();
App.ProductsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  ...
  itemController: 'Product',
  ...
});
```

...each items of `ProductsController` will get a `ProductController` automatically.

Here the discussion on GitHub https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/1637